# Why does current user return nil via GET requests on another domain using the same browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I have a website similar to Instapaper or Pocket where I want to save incoming websites through a browser extension or via the bookmarklet.

I was able to do this with the bookmarklet by using a token that finds the user and saves the page. However for the sake of simplicity I wanted to removed the need for the token and base the save on the currently signed in user.

The problem is I can't figure out how to make this work consistently. I have a route setup /foo that when you GET returns the `current_user` (as a test)

When I do this from the **Chrome extension** it works. However if I try this from the **bookmarklet** or the **Safari Extension** `current_user` returns `nil`

**TL;DR / Summary**

How can I make a GET request to mysite.com/ping from a location other than mysite.com and have `current_user` return as that user instead of nil.

---

Thanks for any insight and help. Instapaper seems to use this approach so I know it's possible, I just don't know how to get it to work with Devise / Rails

---

**Things I've tried:**

- Skipping and requiring auth for that controller action.
- Skipping `protect_from_forgery` (No warning in logs about this so don't think it's the issue at all)

**Other Info**

When I try requiring auth I get a 401 back and the response text is the html of the login page.

I've tried various CORS configurations (via Rack Cors) and haven't been able to make a difference. I have a pretty open policy given the nature of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much troubleshooting and debugging I figured out the issue comes down to **cookies**.

1. I simply cannot read cookies from a external request for the bookmarklet. I'll have to keep using a token (not a big deal)
2. Chrome given the correct permissions allows you to send your session data/cookies to your authorized website. Thus why it works.
3. This is a little harder to do in Safari but still possible so I should be able to make this work.

This website https://chunlianglyu.com/2014/11/27/from-chrome-extension-to-safari-extension/ **seems** to have have the answers to my questions and I should be able to make it work based on the info there.